# Можно ли в GAS вызвать функцию из переменной?

Tags: google-apps-script

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли вызвать функцию, имя которой присвоено переменной? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через eval()

Пример:

```
function test111(){
  return 'function test111';
}

function go(){
  var a = 'test111()';

  Logger.log(eval(a));
}
```

В журнале выдаст "function test111".

Только, если имя функции у Вас без скобок - не забудьте их добавить при вызове eval(). Иначе получите все тело функции.

Comment: Сергей Пряничкин, спасибо! Привычка не использовать eval не дала подумать в этом направлении

Comment: @Sturmer , вы можете пометить ответ как решение.

Comment: через eval не удается запустить функции работающие с API, очень жаль....